# Talend convert ENUM to string

Tags: talend

I have a migration task from mysql via talend to Salesforce. I have ENUM field in mysql and a text string in Salesforce. Which function should i append to convert ENUM to string? Now i have an error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String
```

Comment: Can you please provide mor edetails about your job and the used query to import data ?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 : tMap 
You can use tmap to convert to string from Object by explicit casting.
[image]

Option2 : tConvertType 
You can use tConvertType component and change the datatype in the output schema of the component to String.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since Talend 6.3, there is an option in tMap "Property Settings" (upper left corner) : Enable auto-conversion of types. Just check the box, see if it converts your Object type (input) to the expected String type in the output.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

explictly cast your ENUM object to String.
(String)(ENUM_object)